# svn update - force user to specify revision

Tags: svn, working-copy

I want to configure certain SVN working copy so that it is impossible to do `svn update` without specifying desired revision (`-r`). I want this because doing just `svn update` may update the working copy to a revision, that the user is unaware of. Example:

1. At 12:40 user A checks the SVN log for latest revisions and checks that all the revisions (HEAD being revision 123) are ok.
2. At 12:41 user B commits new, buggy, untested and generally ugly revision 124.
3. At 12:42 user A does not know about revision 124 and does `svn update`, which is bad, because he beleives, that he updated to 123.

I know that the SVN client replies `Updated to revision 124.`, but I also know that the users ignore important replies. This wouldn't happen, if user A was forced to specify `-r 123`.

Is there a way to achieve this in Subversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea of a svn workflow has a **big** problem:

B commits `r124`.
A checks out `r123`.

Now A cannot commit his changes (in the same branch) without updating to B's revision first. If he had changed any file touched by B, `svn` would tell him to update to HEAD first.

Note that in case B knew his changes are "bad", he should commit them to another branch and not to `trunk`.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply! The working copy isn't meant to be edited and commited, it is used as a "read-only" or "production" copy, that is why I need to force user to know which revision he is updating to.

Comment: Then you should handle the `svn update` or better `svn checkout` in the build script itself.